# Fastlane match does not install keys

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

I have a working setup of fastlane and [match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/). Building my iOS app using fastlane works fine on my mac

```
desc "Builds the app for the Beta distribution"
lane :build_adhoc do
    match(type: "adhoc", readonly: true)
    build_app(scheme: "MyApp", export_method: "ad-hoc")
end
```

Now I want to build the app on my CI server but there it fails because it cannot sign the app. I noticed that running `match adhoc --readonly`  on the CI server installs the correct provisioning profiles and the **certificates** but not the **keys**.

[image]

I thought that the entire idea of Match was that it imports also the signing **keys** and not only the certificates.